# Script showing bad interpreter and will not run

Tags: perl

I was sent a perl script over mail and asked to run it .I placed it on my local drive as is but when I tried to run the script it shows me

```
/usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I checked and usr/bin/ does have perl in there .I am not sure what is wrong.I checked a bit and looks like I am missing some spaces or something ..I tried adding those at the end of 
usr/bin/perl and at the end of the file but that didnt help either.
I even tried to use dos2unix

```
dos2unix oldfile newfile
```

'dos2unix' not found.This is on MacOSX.
Might I also mention that I am sshing into my mac using my windows machine at home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of `dos2unix`, you can use `tr` (on Mac OS X) to strip the DOS / Windows new-lines:

```
tr -d '\r' < old.pl > new.pl
```

This will solve the "bad interpreter" issue.

"Can't locate Gpu.pm in @INC" is a different issue. Either you don't have `Gpu.pm` installed on your Mac (or whichever computer on which you are running this, I'm confused by your comments) or it's not in your include path. I don't who what that script is or what it does. A quick look on http://search.cpan.org/ revealed nothing.

If you can get that Perl module (presumably from whoever supplied `oldfile`), you'll have to ensure it is in [`@INC`](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/05/14/mod_perl.html#the_@inc_array).

Comment: Tried this too .It fails also saying Can't locate Gpu.pm in @INC

Comment: That is a different issue. You are missing a Perl module called "Gpu.pm". I don't know what that is or what it does, sorry.

Comment: your problem now is that your don't have the following perl module on your system "Gpu.pm".  You need to use cpan to download it

Comment: @ennuikiller: Gpu.pm is in CPAN? Do you have a URI for that?

Answer (score 9):

You're on the right track. Your script has DOS style newlines at the end, which is not supported by your kernel.

The solution is to use something to convert the DOS newlines to Unix style. `dos2unix` would presumably work if you had it, so use something else equivalent.

Comment: Can you tell me where to get dos2unix? I mean I downloaded it from sourgeforge then unzip it and copy over dos2unix.exe to say dos2unix.exe oldfile newfile .It says -bash: ./dos2unix.exe: cannot execute binary file

Comment: You downloaded a Windows executable to your Mac and it didn't work?

Comment: Alright I go to C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\Downloads\dos2unix-5.3.1-win32\bin and say dos2unix oldfile newfile .It says newfile no such file or directory .I would expect the command to make the new file ..right?

Comment: But you said, "'dos2unix' not found.This is on MacOSX.". That is not a Mac OS X path!

Comment: No earlier one I tried on MacOSX and then I also tried converting on my windows

Answer (score 3):

Do this in vim:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

save the file and try running it again

execute: vim

when vim opens go to command mode by hitting the escape key .... at the command prompt (:) type:  `%s/^M//g`.  This will remove all "^M" characters from the file.

Comment: Can you explain a bit  more? where do I add this ?

Comment: still see the pattern not found thingy .Just to be sure there is no space anywhere above in %s/^M//g  right

Comment: If you ran this after running `tr`, then you've already got rid of the DOS newlines so there's nothing to do!

Comment: But that would have been saved in the new file right? This old file should still have the ^M characters

Comment: @Manish: You probably want to Ctrl+V Ctrl+M to get a raw CR into your `:%s/^M//g` inside vim.

Comment: Ah yes. ^M is **one character**.

Answer (score 2):

dos2unix in Perl:

```
perl -pi -e 'tr/\r//d' file.txt
```