# /usr/bin/env bad interpreter

Tags: bash

Trying to get Amazon's EC2 command line tools to work. This is what my .bash_profile looks like. I get the error: /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/x11/bin:/usr/texbin:$PATH
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$PATH
EC2_HOME=~/.ec2
PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=`ls $EC2_HOME/pk-*.pem`
EC2_CERT=`ls $EC2_HOME/cert-*.pem`
JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/

export PATH
```

Does anybody see anything wrong with this? I am not sure what I doing wrong.

Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/env`

```
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  34720 Sep  8  2011 /usr/bin/env
zmjones-mbp:.ec2 zmjones$ /usr/bin/env
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/x3/vrw5029d1rj9xblj8bmxl0m00000gn/T/ 
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-91y0bp/Render
OLDPWD=/Users/zmjones
USER=zmjones
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-H3JJsl/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-n2bT2X/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
PATH=/users/zmjones/.ec2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/x11/bin:/usr/texbn
PWD=/Users/zmjones/.ec2
 JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/zmjones
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0
LOGNAME=zmjones
EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=pk-mykey.pem
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-6kkP5t/org.x:0
EC2_CERT=cert-mycert.pem
 _=/usr/bin/env
```

Partial solution: `tr -d '\r' < /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair > /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair`

This seems to allow the commands to execute, but they now don't work. For example, I downloaded a new copy of the ec2 api tools, put them in `~/.ec2` tried `ec2-describe-images -o amazon` and got the bad interpreter error. I renamed `ec2-describe-images` to `ec2-describe-images.bak` ran the `tr` command listed above and tried it again. I then receive a `permission denied error`. When I run it with sudo it tells me that `EC2_HOME` isn't set, but `echo $EC2_HOME` indicates that it is. I ran `chmod +x ec2-describe-images` and now I am back to the same bad interepreter error.

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/env`

Comment: -r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  34720 Sep  8  2011 /usr/bin/env

Comment: Well that doesn't look unusual. Next try running `/usr/bin/env`, if it's successful it should print your current environment.

Comment: Are you on OS X?  If so, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952612/mac-os-usr-bin-env-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted

Comment: put it in the main post. As for the perl related post. How am I supposed to do that. What folder should I check the attr on? `~/.ec2`?

Comment: I bet `/users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair` has DOS line-endings. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8556539/78845 for a solution.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Good call, I bet you're absolutely right.

Comment: Lucky guess ;) I've added this as an answer.

Comment: You're a big fan of export, but don't like to look it up, are you?

Comment: Well I have no idea what I am doing. So I guess yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair` has DOS [line-endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

To fix:

```
mv /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair.bak
tr -d '\r' < /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair.bak > /users/zmjones/.ec2/bin/ec2-add-keypair
```

Comment: Turns out that doesn't work. I can get the command to execute, but it doesn't actually do what it is supposed to. Not sure what is up.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on Windows because I had the wrong header in my bash files. I had
`#!/usr/bin/bash` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env bash` which is the portable version.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exactly the same problem.

The CAUSE of the problem is the **"unarchiver tool"**.

I've installed a third party unarchiver tool. It might change the line-endings of the files during the unzipping process.

After I realized this, I deleted this tool and re-unziped the EC2 zip ball using the native unzip tool. And the problem was solved.

Hope this might be useful for you guys with the same problem.